# Is every group $G$ such that $\bigcap\limits_nG^{(n)}$ is trivial, solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group, such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G^{(n)} = E$, where $G^{(n)}$ is the n-th element of the derived series of $G$, and $E$ is the trivial subgroup of $G$.

Does $G$ always have to be solvable?

For finite groups the answer obviously is "yes", but the situation with infinite groups seems to be much more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, such a group need not be solvable. To get an example, for each $i$ let $G_i$ be a group of derived length $i$.

Then the restricted direct product $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}G_i$ satisfies the condition that $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}G^{(i)} = \{e\}$, but there is no $n$ such that $G^{(n)} = \{e\}$. Here by restricted direct product I mean where we only consider those sequences with finite support.

Comment: Nonabelian free groups are also examples, although the proof needs a bit of work.